# Integer is being transformed to an object

Tags: php

Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/aR299wuz

When I open the file, for example: `rate.php?permalink=game-of-thrones&rating=5`

The parameters from the array right before executing the query is returning  `rating` as an object instead of an integer, although I get it from the URL like this: `(int)$_GET['rating'];`

This is the error I get:

`Array ( [:permalink] => game-of-thrones [:rating] => Rating Object ( [dbh:Rating:private] => PDO Object ( ) ) [:ip] => ::1 [:userid] => 32 )`

`Catchable fatal error: Object of class Rating could not be converted to string in D:\xampp\htdocs\TVShowCalendar\inc\rate.php on line 20`

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the `$rating` variable on line `33` with a new object before using it on line `35`.

Consider using another name for either variable.

Comment: Right! I am so blind. Thank you very much for pointing that out. This was causing all issues.

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this answer as the solution so other users might find this. :)

Comment: Of course. I had to wait 10 minutes before doing so.